# High-dimensional embedding similarity normalization

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, pca, large-data, similarities

I've generated a big set of **very high-dimensional embeddings** (7300 words with 1700 dimensions each) from a QnA dataset. I'm trying to visualize them and what I do is to apply [`truncatedSVD`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html#sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD) (a PCA which centers the data) to obtain 50 dimensions and then pass those to [`TSNE`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) in order to visualize them in 2d.

The problem is that those embeddings include lots of verb conjugations and synonyms, so I would like to apply some type of algorithm to those high-dimensional embeddings (like kNN or cosine similarity) in order to obtain clusters or groups of **similar embeddings** represented by a single vector for each of those groups (without reducing their dimensionality since that is done later through SVD and TSNE).

The idea that I was thinking about is to obtain groups of similar vectors and add the ones of a group together in order to obtain an embedding which is representative of that cluster. This could be translated into obtaining a **vector subspace** for each of those groups.

I would want to know which could be the best way to face this problem.

Comment: Have you tried using tSNE after some word2vec and sum-normalizing the vectors? Then your Cosine similarity would work.